# Enumerator Int value convert to string three-digit base 2 number

Tags: c#, .net, string, int, converters

I have an enum like the following:

```
public enum AudioEncoding
{
    PCM_24Bit = 0,
    ADPCM_24Bit = 1,
    MPEG2_128kBit = 2
}
```

and I need to convert the value of the enumerator in a string three-digit base 2 number, like `"010"`.

I've tried the following to convert in a string base 2 number:

```
int audioEncInt = (int)AudioEncoding.ADPCM_24Bit;
string audioEncStr = Convert.ToString(audioEncInt, 2);
```

It works correctly, but it returns a string value of `"10"`. How can I return a string value of `"010"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a constant 3 character's you are needed you could use PadLeft

```
int audioEncInt = (int)AudioEncoding.ADPCM_24Bit;
string audioEncStr = Convert.ToString(audioEncInt, 2).PadLeft(3, '0');
```

That will add zero's to the left of the string if it isn't the specified length

Answer (score 2):

```
var audioEncStr = Convert.ToString(audioEncInt, 2).PadLeft(3,'0');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the [string.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07.aspx) method like so:

```
int audioEncInt = (int)AudioEncoding.ADPCM_24Bit;
string audioEncStr = Convert.ToString(audioEncInt, 2);
audioEncStr = audioEncStr.PadLeft(3, '0');
```